# Speaker setup as keyboard

Tags: keyboard, bluetooth

I connected a speaker with bluetooth, was not concentrating with installation, bluetooth is picking the speaker up as a keyboard.  How do I change the setting for the Speaker to a Music device and not a keyboard device.

Comment: You should add additional details: Which model of computer, which model of speaker, what troubleshooting steps have you taken so far?

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if this will fix the issue for you, but for some magical reason, it worked for me. 
I removed the speaker from the list of Bluetooth devices that were paired and was ready to start again when I decided to just listen to music through the internal speaker. Pressed play and got the sound coming from Bluetooth box. It doesn't show in the Sound settings (it says Internal Speakers are being used) and it's not on the Bluetooth panel, although the bluetooth is showing a connection. Hope it works for you, although given the nature of this fix, don't be surprised if it doesn't.

BTW, I'm using a mini Smart Box II speaker on a MacBook Pro with Sierra 10.12.6.

Answer (score 0):

If all else fails you can reset both the macOS Bluetooth Device List and Bluetooth Controller. However, this will reset **all** connected Bluetooth devices, including a keyboard and mouse.

**In other words, this will remove all existing pairing information for Bluetooth devices, so each will need to be reconnected.**

Before commencing, you will need to have the Bluetooth icon showing in the menu bar. If it is not there, open System Preferences > Bluetooth and enable the option *Show Bluetooth in Menu Bar*.

**Resetting the macOS Bluetooth Device List and Bluetooth Controller**

Follow these steps:

1. Hold down both the <kbd>Shift</kbd> and <kbd>Option</kbd> keys and at the same time click on the Bluetooth icon in the menu bar. Once the menu is showing, release the keys.
2. From the Bluetooth menu, choose Debug > Remove All Devices
3. Hold down both the <kbd>Shift</kbd> and <kbd>Option</kbd> keys again and at the same time click on the Bluetooth icon in the menu bar.
4. From the Bluetooth menu,  choose Debug > Reset the Bluetooth Module
5. Restart your Mac
6. Setup your bluetooth devices again

Let us know whether this helps.